# Can Hdfs has different replication policy

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Can I have different replication policy in different folder in HDFS?
For example the files in folder /important_data I wanna that it's replicate is 3, but the files in folder /normal_data I just wanna it's replicate is 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use setrep to set the replication

```
hadoop fs –setrep –w 3 -R /my/dir1
hadoop fs –setrep –w 1 -R /my/dir2
```

You set custom replication on file too.

```
hadoop fs –setrep –w 3 /my/file
```

Here is the documentation
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#setrep